# How to deal with timeouts when querying database with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that returns a promise.

```
this.getDataFromMainDB()
    .then()
    .catch();
```

This function gets more than 300.000 records from the main DB and stores it on the microservice DB, so that it can do its job.

It uses an AsyncGenerator (with 1.000 limit), KnexJS to connect to SQL Server.

Now, timeouts occur during this query and it stops.

I thought of using another function on that catch that would take the last ID recorded in the microservice DB and restart the query from than on.

My question is:

- This approach would generate many concurrent processes, restarting this query in parallel each time a timeout occurs;

OR

- The process is always the same, it would always be the same process restarting on timeouts, until it finishes the gathering of data?

Comment: If you're using PG as your DB, you might want to consider streams: https://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Streams

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, why does the query time out? What "microservice DB" are you using? Is the DB timing out or the request to it? Do you get results in the form of streamed data or everything at once?

Comment: If you can't stream it, then you might as well paginate your query so you don't get all 300,000 records at once.

Comment: Query is being paginated in the AsyncGenrator (1000 limit). The query times out and fails to complete, ending up on that catch statement. THe question is wheter is it possibile to call another function to restart from the point it stoped, without opening multiple parallel processes. Streams are a great idea, but I am using SQL Server. I will check if it is possible to use it.